--base-href for flutter build in Jenkins
In My Jenkins pipeline I need to pass the value of --base-href as "/online/" in flutter build command
I am giving flutter build command as below:
pipeline{
agent {  
    label 'XXXXX'
}

stages{
    stage( 'check command' ){
        steps{
            script{
              sh """
              flutter build web --base-href \\"/online/\\"
              """
            }
        }
    }
}

}
but during pipeline execution command is executing like below
11:23:16  Started by user XXXXX
11:23:16  Replayed #21
11:23:16  [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
11:23:16  [Pipeline] node
11:23:16  Running on XXXXX in 
/app/var/lib/jenkins_slaves/XXXXX/workspace/po/cicd/demo/test
11:23:16  [Pipeline] {
11:23:16  [Pipeline] stage
11:23:16  [Pipeline] { (check command)
11:23:16  [Pipeline] script
11:23:16  [Pipeline] {
11:23:16  [Pipeline] sh
11:23:17  + flutter build web --base-href '"/online/"'

In pipeline execution as you can see in logs the value of --base-href coming as '"/online/"' but I need it as "/online/", command should execute like below:
flutter build web --base-href "/online/"


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
